# In Django Project How to authenticate Graphql API when using Aws Congnito authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Project Technology stack :

1. Python Django web Framework 2.2
2. Graphql
3. sqlalchemy ORM
4. AWS Cognito for User Authentication

I have followed this article  - https://djangostars.com/blog/bootstrap-django-app-with-cognito/

It's working for me for Django rest API but I have Graphql API so how to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AWS services, at this point is SSO solution: AWS Cognito, the easiest way that you can try is to make it work with another AWS native service.

You can try **AWS AppSync**: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/designing-a-graphql-api.html

Then trying to authorize with **AWS Cognito**:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authorization-use-cases.html